# what should be used to store comments given by any users such as one in any blog or in FB?.

Tags: android, sql, facebook, comments

i am working on sample SocialNetworking type of application, In which any logged in users can give comments on any profile of user and that given comment is shown for that commented user such as in FB. I am using SQLite Database for storing values such as username, password, address etc.

Now problem is that what should i use to store the given comments in database. Here i can use TEXT field to store user given comments but as the comments will be of any size so i cant use that. My point here is that as Android provides sqlite as light weight so it wont be feasible to use. So is there any another approach to do so...

please help me out. thanking you...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a remote database to hold the values of comments? Then whenever needed, just fetch its value from the remote database?

Comment: i would like to know more about remote database?.. will you please suggest me from where can i start?.. Any links, tutorial etc..... Thanks for advice....

Comment: One option is google app engine http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html It has datastore and tons of services you can use (user authentication, remote API, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use varchar or TEXT since SQLite does not use sizes when declaring the VARCHAR type. In fact, it almost doesn't use the type either. You can store TEXT in an INT column in SQLite. And SQLite will never truncate a TEXT column.

Comment: I think that storing comments with TEXT, VARCHAR type wont be feasible choice as the application will run android device may be there performance issue that app runs slowly and badly may hang on... And "what is this INT column in SQLite".  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yes it won't be performance oriented , but i guess you want something to save on SQLLite db , otherwise you can use remote database . In which you have to connect with db on server by providing server IP address and password. Or you can make a web service which saves and retrieve comments on the server .